# usePrevious vs useMemo

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a react component where we keep track of all the filters in a redux state. The filters are stored in an object which can change over different files and whenever any value inside this object changes few api calls should be done.
As I do the api calls in useEffect in different components, putting this object as a dependency creates the issue of redundant api calls with same payload.
To avoid this I found 2 solutions:

1. use useMemo e.g. const newFilter = useMemo(() => ({filterObj}), [filterObj]);
2. to create a custom hook called as usePrevious (https://www.developerway.com/posts/implementing-advanced-use-previous-hook) as suggested in the link and then kind of tag my filterObj to this hook

I do like both of these options but I wanted to know which is a better solution in terms of efficiency as I believe in the second option there is useEffect continuously running till my component is mounted to serve this usePrevious hook and the first one does memoization.
Please do inform me as which is an elegant and good way to approach this issue.

Thank you

I have tried both of the solutions but I am not aware of how to test their behavior and efficiency.